# how do I check java code duplications from files

Tags: java, algorithm, file, code-duplication, plagiarism-detection

I am going through a project where I have to check the **plagiarism** between two files.In two files there have some **java code**.That means if there are two files named a.java and b.java and in two files have some **java code** which was written in **.java class** and I have to check the duplicacy in percantage between the java code which was written the two files.
can anyone tell me how can I solve this problem?I am a beginner.

Comment: Here are 20 algorithms you can use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric

Comment: You may find this site interesting:
https://theory.stanford.edu/~aiken/moss/
From what I recall, there exists  a third party similarity checker, but I think they also provide an API to allow independant usage. I do note that they state "Moss is not a system for completely automatically detecting plagiarism." (see the site for the full statement).

Comment: Following on from my previous comment, there is a paper linked from that site:
http://theory.stanford.edu/~aiken/publications/papers/sigmod03.pdf
which exposes the technology used by the service Moss, it is an interesting read (whilst quite mathematical in places, these are mostly proofs rather than implementation detail). It is mostly about 'fingerprinting k-grammes' (which are k length fragments of a document) and a process called 'Winnowing', to effectively select a subset of fingerprints to characterise documents - from what I could make out!

Comment: @BillNaylor I have to solve this my problem with my own java code without any third party checker. Is there any algorithm that may help to solve this?

Comment: If you look at the paper I reference, this details a number of algorithms (it seems you do need a number to perform the task you require). From what I could make out it seems you 1) fingerprint each 'k-gramme', 2) associate each fingerprint with a position in the document, 3) use the 'Winnowing' algorithm to identify which (fingerprint, position) pairs characterise the document, 4) resolve documents against each other. Check the paper!

Comment: @BillNaylor thanks for your feedback.I think this paper will help me

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do so, but in general, you have to use third party service.

Example Solution 1:
Install plugin to your IDE. For example, if you are using Eclipse, [PMD](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-pmd) supports duplicated code checking.

Example Solution 2:
If you are using version control system like GitHub, you can add plugins to your repository and it will do the check for you. For instance, you can use plugin named [Codacy](https://www.codacy.com/). It is an automatic testing tool used in CI/CD, which supports duplicated code checking.

Comment: I am going through a project where I can't use any third party service. Is there any algorithm available for which I can solve the duplicacy of the code from files in the java platform?